# Converting Files with regexp Pattern in sed

Tags: regex, sed

I want to turn this (Mitarbeiter.csv):

```
Max;Mustermann;02.03.1964;501;GL;Prokurist
Monika;Mueller;02.02.1972;500;Sek;Chefsekretaerin
Michael;Maier;06.07.1985;617;Aquise;-
```

into this (header-content.html):

```
<tr><td>Max</td><td>Mustermann</td><td>501</td></tr>
<tr><td>Monika</td><td>Mueller</td><td>500</td></tr>
<tr><td>Michael</td><td>Maier</td><td>617</td></tr>
```

by using sed

I've tried:

```
sed 's#^\([^\]+\);\([^\]+\);[^\]+;\([^\]+\);.*$#<tr><td>\2</td><td>\1</td><td>\3</td></tr>\n#g' <Mitarbeiter.csv >header-content.html
```

but that does nothing. Output is same as Mitarbeiter.csv

Comment: Is your sed command supposed to be missing it's output?

Comment: naah, was just a formatting error, corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few points,

1. you need the `-r` switch for extended regex patterns
2. Sed is greedy, and even `-r` does not support non greedy matching
3. The `g` flag is a [special get flag](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-57), you probably don't want this

So your command should be:

```
sed -r 's#^([^\;]+);([^\;]+);[^\;]+;([^\;]+);.*$#<tr><td>\1</td><td>\2</td><td>\3</td></tr>#' < Mitarbeiter.csv > header-content.html
```

Note that your items cannot have a semicolon in them, as that is the field separator. If you a a true csv file, this won't work, as it **will not ignore** an escaped semicolon, either wrapped in quotes or with an escape char.

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked fine.
The 'g' is the FLAG for global matching as described here: http://ss64.com/bash/sed.html

Comment: The 'g' flag is indeed for "global" substitution, but you still don't need it, since your regexp is anchored to the beginning of the search area.  There is only one "**`^`**".

Answer (score 2):

`awk` might be a little better suited to what you're trying to do:

```
awk -F\; '{printf "<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>\n",$1,$2,$4}'
```

Comment: sadly i have to use SED, I'm not allowed to use awk ;(

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -r -ne 's:^([^;]+);([^;]+);[^;]+;([^;]+);.*:<tr><td>\1</td><td>\2</td><td>\3</td></tr>:p'
```

Or if you're using OSX or an older version of FreeBSD or NetBSD, replace the `-r` with `-E` to use extended regular expressions.

If you want to skip using ERE for portability (i.e. you're using Solaris or HP/UX or somesuch), the regexp might be:

```
^\([^;][^;]*\);\([^;][^;]*\);[^;]*;\([^;][^;]*\);.*
```

Note that these both require at least 1 character per field.  If fields are allowed to be empty ... well, update your question before we more spend more time on things that might not be necessary.  :-)

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked, too. Also I don't think the -ne (and p flag) parameters are necessary.

Comment: Glad it worked!  The difference with -n (and the p flag) is that with them, improperly formatted input lines will not be passed through to your output.  If you can GUARANTEE that your input file won't have comments or headers or bad formatting, you can skip the "safety net".

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to use sed?

```
awk '{print "<tr><td>"$1"</td><td>"$2"</td><td>"$4"</td></tr>}
    ' IFS=';' Mitarbeiter.csv > header-content.html
```

Comment: sadly i have to use SED, I'm not allowed to use awk ;(

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using sed, you can try:

```
$ p='\([^;]*\);'
$ sed "s@$p$p$p$p.*@<tr><td>\1</td><td>\2</td><td>\4</td></tr>@" \
         Mitarbeiter.csv > header-content.html
```